# How to get rid of the EditText baseline padding?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm trying to figure out how to get rid of the padding between the border of the element and the baseline. The padding seems to be there by default, but it gets annoying since it is impossible to properly align the text on top with the EditText baseline. You can see the problem on the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly what you're after (based on your drawing), then you're not asking about baseline padding, but rather left padding between the border of the EditText and the start of the text.

If this is the case, then you can use `android:paddingLeft` attribute:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="0px" />
```

That said, it would only really matter if you are not showing the border of the EditText.  If you do, then the text (label?) above it would align nicely against the left border of the EditText.

*Update:* Based on discussion in comments, it sounds like padding doesn't have an impact on the position of the line.  In this case, it may be necessary to either set a custom background, or as an option, set background to white (`@android:color/white`) or transparent and then use a simply drawableBottom to place a line below the text.  Unfortunately, I don't have access to an Android dev environment at the moment to try this out.

Comment: That won't move the line to the edge of the view. I think the 9patch image used by default for the Edittext has the padding and you can't remove it, unless you provide your own custom background. You can test that simply by setting a colour as the background and seeing how the text automatically changes position. (android:background="@color/white")

Comment: As @NikosHidalgo just said, applying the padding only moves the text, but the line stays at the same place, regardless of the left/right, start/end padding

Comment: @NikosHidalgo I don't have access to an Android dev environment at the moment so can't check, but it would be an interesting test. the 0px left padding would make the text start directly against the left border.  It would be strange indeed if the line didn't start where the text did.

Comment: @jack'smedullaoblongata If that's the case, you may need to provide your own background for the text box.  If you need the line, it's fairly easy with the background drawable.

Comment: @AleksG I had the same issue in the past and I tried padding, even negative margin and nothing moved the line, only the text. I ended up adding padding to the textviews around the edittext so that they would align when placed on top of one another.

Comment: I had this trouble with the bottom padding. If you align a TextView with the EditText, both textes are not aligned. It's a pain in the a**...ended add moving the text in the Textview to match the text in the TextView.

Comment: @NikosHidalgo Exactly, my only thought was to set padding on the TextView, but then you have to align all other elements underneath as well, and it is just a hacky solution. I was really hoping for a straightforward solution, which as it seems is not possible.

Comment: @jack'smedullaoblongata I know it should be easier but every thread I searched pointed towards creating a custom background instead